# Identifying a connector type

Tags: identification, connector

I lost a cable from my Navatics Mito drone to connect it to a PC. The drone side of the cable is the tricky one. I tried to use a connector identificator website, but no luck.

Here is the picture. It is 12 mm diameter, 4 pins with 2 male/female plastic guides for positioning.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more pictures? It looks like a locking barrel connector. Are there any part numbers visible?

Comment: Colloquially, 12mm circular connectors are termed "M12" connectors.  If you google that, will return thouands of hits.  Problem is, this particular one has four pins (pretty common) and two or three keying indents, which is highly unusual.  In fact, they may be custom-made.  Finding this, or a mate to it, is going to be challenging at best.

Comment: Yes, please pictures from various directions. The notches are bit washed...

Answer (score 5):

As @rdtsc said, this is an M12 connector.  Uniquely, in my experience, M12 connectors use the term "code" instead of "keying", with different codes informally reserved for specific applications.  This is a D-code male receptacle: male, because it has pins; receptacle, because it has threads on the outside (or appears to; if the threads are on the inside of the shell then it is a plug - "plug" and "receptacle" can be somewhat confusing with M12, just find a part with a picture that matches what you want).  D-code is *generally* reserved for ethernet.  Many manufacturers will make equivalent versions of this connector, choose whichever you like in accordance with your application and pocketbook.

[image]

Image from: https://blog.muellerelectric.com/m12-cable-coding-decoded-which-is-right-for-you-1-0

Comment: some of the internet web pages call it `industrial ethernet` connector